# Sort table row with Mootools

Tags: javascript, html-table, mootools

Well I'm trying to implement the drag and drop sortable rows on table using Mootools. The issue that I'm banging my head all this morning and could figure out it's solution, here's the HTML table :

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item">
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's the Javascipt:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  /* create sortables */
      var d = $$('tr');
  var sb = new Sortables(d, {
    /* set options */
    clone:true,
    revert: true,
    /* initialization stuff here */
    initialize: function() { 

    },
    /* once an item is selected */
    onStart: function(el) { 
      el.setStyle('background','#add8e6');
    },
    /* when a drag is complete */
    onComplete: function(el) {
      el.setStyle('background','#ddd');
      //build a string of the order

    }
  });
});
```

And here's a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t1tht0p9/) . Much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly didn't you manage? Can you explain more the functionality you want to achieve?

Comment: Your code works for me, please be more clear on what is not working for you...

Comment: Sortable will grab each child of the list(s) and make them sortable. You have targeted the tr elements - this makes the td elements sortable. I think you want to target the tbody so that the tr elements are sortable and not each td. See here: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1tht0p9/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem you are having as I understand it:

You wish to make the rows sortable? And your Fiddle example has all cells individually sortable.

Your issue is here:

```
var d = $$('tr');
var sb = new Sortables(d);
```

You have passed in all tr's as sortable lists. This means all td's are sortable.

You need to pass in:

```
var d = $('tbody');
var sb = new Sortables(d);
```

Mootools Docs state:

> Arguments:
>   [1] list - (mixed) required, the list or lists that will become sortable.

A list in this case is any element (or array of elements) whose children will become sortable.

See here: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1tht0p9/1/)